# BigDump v0.35b vulnerability

Tags: php, known-vulnerabilities, file-upload

I dont understand what the problem with BigDump v0.35b.
[This](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/32479/) site says that it have problem.
But i dont understand it.

Problem here?

```
if (!$error && isset($_REQUEST["uploadbutton"]))
{ if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["dumpfile"]["tmp_name"]) && ($_FILES["dumpfile"]["error"])==0)
  { 
    $uploaded_filename=str_replace(" ","_",$_FILES["dumpfile"]["name"]);
    $uploaded_filename=preg_replace("/[^_A-Za-z0-9-\.]/i",'',$uploaded_filename);
    $uploaded_filepath=str_replace("\\","/",$upload_dir."/".$uploaded_filename);

    do_action('file_uploaded');

    if (file_exists($uploaded_filename))
    { echo ("<p class=\"error\">File $uploaded_filename already exist! Delete and upload again!</p>\n");
    }
    else if (!preg_match("/(\.(sql|gz|csv))$/i",$uploaded_filename))
    { echo ("<p class=\"error\">You may only upload .sql .gz or .csv files.</p>\n");
    }
    else if (!@move_uploaded_file($_FILES["dumpfile"]["tmp_name"],$uploaded_filepath))
    { echo ("<p class=\"error\">Error moving uploaded file ".$_FILES["dumpfile"]["tmp_name"]." to the $uploaded_filepath</p>\n");
      echo ("<p>Check the directory permissions for $upload_dir (must be 777)!</p>\n");
    }
    else
    { echo ("<p class=\"success\">Uploaded file saved as $uploaded_filename</p>\n");
    }
  }
  else
  { echo ("<p class=\"error\">Error uploading file ".$_FILES["dumpfile"]["name"]."</p>\n");
  }
}
```

With what?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [CVE](http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2008-6660) details and you can see the problem:

> Unrestricted file upload vulnerability in bigdump.php in Alexey Ozerov
>   BigDump 0.29b allows remote attackers to execute arbitrary code by
>   uploading a file with an executable extension followed by a .sql
>   extension, then accessing this file via a direct request.

I can upload `cmd.php.sql`, then access it as it runs a PHP shell, for instance. That means I can run as the web server user.

Comment: Your web server must be misconfigured to execute that as PHP.